# Returning column duplicates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, common-table-expression, exists

I'm learning PostgreSQL and am struggling with this problem.

I've got an `olympics` table set up that I'm querying and returning results from. I'm querying to find countries and the number of golds they have won, like this:

```
SELECT country, golds 
FROM (SELECT distinct country, sum(gold_medals) as golds
      FROM olympics where year >= 2000 group by country
     ) foo
WHERE (golds < 10) 
ORDER BY golds desc limit 10;
```

This accurately returns:

```
   country   | golds 
-------------+-------
 Turkey      |     9
 Bulgaria    |     8
 Azerbaijan  |     6
 Estonia     |     6
 Georgia     |     6
 North Korea |     6
 Thailand    |     6
 Nigeria     |     6
 Uzbekistan  |     5
 Lithuania   |     5
```

I need to return the countries that have won the same number of golds in this time (ie Lithuania and Uzbekistan with 5, and all of those with 6).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Run another aggregation. This time `GROUP BY` the number of gold medals. Then `JOIN`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT country, sum(gold_medals) AS golds
   FROM   olympics
   WHERE  year >= 2000
   GROUP  BY country
   HAVING sum(gold_medals) < 10   -- ? No more allowed?
   )
SELECT c.*
FROM   cte c
JOIN  (
    SELECT golds
    FROM   cte
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    ) ties USING (golds)
ORDER  BY golds DESC, country
LIMIT  10;
```

- Remove the useless `DISTINCT` from your original query. `GROUP BY` already does the job.
- I am using a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to simplify my job.

Alternative with [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT country, sum(gold_medals) AS golds
   FROM   olympics
   WHERE  year >= 2000
   GROUP  BY country
   HAVING sum(gold_medals) < 10   -- ? No more allowed?
   )
SELECT c.*
FROM   cte c
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  country <> c.country -- exclude "self"
   AND    golds  = c.golds
   )
ORDER  BY golds DESC, country
LIMIT  10;
```

Or, to get countries with up to 10 gold medals as array in a single row per number of golds, but only if there are 2 countries or more:

```
SELECT golds, array_agg(country) AS country_list
FROM  (
   SELECT country, sum(gold_medals) AS golds
   FROM   olympics
   WHERE  year >= 2000
   GROUP  BY country
   HAVING sum(gold_medals) < 10   -- ? No more allowed?
   ) sub
GROUP   BY golds
HAVING  count(*) > 1
ORDER   BY 1  DESC;
-- LIMIT   10;    -- not needed, there cannot be more than 10 in this case.
```

The last one is basically a simplified version of [@Nisan.H´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345000/939860).

Answer (score 1):

@ErwinBrandstetter's solution works, but for completeness I'll also throw in the `array_agg` version, which returns the countries lumped together as a string array in a single cell:

```
WITH golds as (
    select
        sum(gold_medals) golds,
        country
    from olympics
    where year >= 2000
    group by country
    )

select 
    golds, 
    array_length(array_agg(country),1) n_countries, 
    array_agg(country) countries
from golds
group by golds
having array_length(array_agg(country),1) > 1
order by golds asc

-- golds , n_countries , countries
--   5   ,     2       , '{lithuania,uzbekistan}'
--   6   ,     6       , '{thailand,"north korea",azerbaijan,nigeria,estonia,georgia}'
```

Comment: Nice addition. I have a few suggestions that wouldn't fit into a comment. Added it to my answer, you may be interested.

Answer (score -1):

Try group by country and golds

```
SELECT country, golds 
FROM (SELECT distinct country, sum(gold_medals) as golds FROM 
olympics where year >= 2000 group by country, golds) foo
WHERE (golds < 10) ORDER BY golds desc limit 10;
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with detecting duplicates.